# WPF - ObservableCollection Binding Failure - .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, observablecollection

Quick summary

- No items show up in my Grid in the GUI of my Application
- Correct columns are listed in grid when it fires up (Picked up collection type)
- CollectionChanged event fires on the ObservableCollection the grid is bound to
- No binding error in the output window (Binds successfully but doesn't register delegate)

**MyView.xaml**

```
 .
 .
 .
<UserControl.Resources>
        <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource
                x:Key="items"
                Source="{Binding Path=Items}"
                AutoFilterMode="And" >
        </xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
<xcdg:DataGridControl 
        Name="dataGrid" 
        ReadOnly="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}}"
     .
     .
     .
```

**MyView.xaml.cs Constructor**

```
    public MyView()
    {
        if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            DataContext = new MyViewModel().Tree;
        initializeComponent();
    }
```

**MyViewModel.cs key parts**

```
 public MyTree Tree { get; set; }

 public MyViewModel()
 {    
         Tree = new MyTree();            
 }
```

**MyTree.cs key parts**

```
 public ObservableCollection<Item> Items{ get; private set; }

 public MyTree()
 {
    Items= new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    Items.CollectionChanged += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Trigger"); };
 }
```

Trigger gets printed on every addition and deletion but the UI still thinks the collection is empty and isn't aware of the updates. Without my extra delegate `Items.CollectionChanged` is `null` (ie the parsed Xaml doesn't cause a listener to be added to the collection)

- What am I doing wrong in trying to
  bind my
  `DataGridCollectionViewSource` to an
  ObservableCollection?

Happy to give more detail, I've tried to abstract away from my use case to the bare bones of the issue. The nesting of the collection may seem ridiculous but it's basically a collection of the nodes in the tree for faster access.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

By adding `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to my Xaml I got some more detailed output.

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource orders}, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
```

Here I think the problem is that `Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged` where I would expect the default to be `CollectionChanged`. I'm still not sure what to do about this though.

```
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Default mode resolved to OneWay
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Attach to Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridControl.ItemsSource (hash=9150720)
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Resolving source 
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Use View from DataGridCollectionViewSource (hash=9026257)
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Activate with root item <null>
 BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Replace item at level 0 with <null>, using accessor {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): GetValue at level 0 from <null> using <null>: <null>
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): TransferValue - got raw value <null>
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): TransferValue - using final value <null>
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Got PropertyChanged event from DataGridCollectionViewSource (hash=9026257) for View
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Deactivate
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Replace item at level 0 with {NullDataItem}
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Use View from DataGridCollectionViewSource (hash=9026257)
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Activate with root item DataGridCollectionView (hash=54545236 Count=0)
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): Replace item at level 0 with DataGridCollectionView (hash=54545236 Count=0), using accessor {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): GetValue at level 0 from DataGridCollectionView (hash=54545236 Count=0) using <null>: DataGridCollectionView (hash=54545236 Count=0)
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): TransferValue - got raw value DataGridCollectionView (hash=54545236 Count=0)
BindingExpression (hash=43320496): TransferValue - using final value DataGridCollectionView (hash=54545236 Count=0)
```

Comment: Care to comment some of the answers?

Comment: Certainly, I got bogged down with another issue, I've tried half with no luck and will try the rest in the morning. I Fully appreciate all of your help, I was surprised to get so many good suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you bind directly to your Items instead of using a Static source?

`<xcdg:DataGridControl Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" />`

I don't have much experience with static item sources, but the word static makes me think its a one-time binding

Answer (score 0):

What if you try binding the Grid directly to the `Items` property, rather than to the `CollectionViewSource`? If that works, then the problem is with the binding of the `CollectionViewSource` to your collection, rather than the Grid's binding to the `CollectionViewSource`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `Source` property of the `CollectionViewSource`:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var items = (CollectionViewSource) FindResource("items");
       items.Source = new MyViewModel().Tree;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something you can try is give the CollectionViewSource a name and then in the code behind call the CollectionViewSource.View.Refresh() method on it after you have loaded it with data.

Many times the problem is that the CollectionViewSource doesn't automatically update even if you make the view an ObservableCollection.

Someone on the web posted a nice class for an AutoRefreshingObservableCollection which I've been using and works well.

Give this a try and let me know if it solves your issue. I have the code for that AutoRefreshingObservableCollection too if you need, reply and I can drop it on my website or something.